# How to get jQuery UI tabs element panels and set visibility on some of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-1.10

## How to get jQuery UI tabs tab elements panel numbers and set CSS style visibility on some of them?

I want to get elements' panel numbers for tabs and set visibility on some of the tabs.

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">1</a>
:
<li><a href="#">10</>
</ul>
<div id="tab-contents">
<div id="tab1">some content</div>
:
<div id="tab1">some content</div>
</div>
```

Get elements panel number by `eq()` or something, then set `style` `visibility = hidden;` or `visible;` for some tab(s).
I tried the following but it does not work for jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery UI 1.10.3.

```
$(function() {
var panelNumber = $("#tabs").eq();
document.getElementById("div#tabs ul li").visibility = 'hidden';
alert(panelNumber);
)};
```

I want to set specified tabs visible and rest of them hidden for the page navigation. Also, I do not want DOM to create or destroy tabs on tabs for navigation, **using CSS visibility is needed for the minimized process time**, because it gets slower. 
**Please answer the question for the `jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery UI 1.10.3` because they deprecated `length` and many others for `jQuery UI 1.9.*` update.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) like so:

**[Working Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/TMuxx/)**

```
 $(function () {
     $("#tabs").tabs();
     $('#tabs li').slice(2, 5).css('visibility', 'hidden');
 });
```

or [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) like so:

**[Working Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/TMuxx/2/)**

```
 $(function () {
     $("#tabs").tabs();
     $('#tabs li:nth-child(even)').css('visibility', 'hidden'); //note: even can be replaced with odd, specific number, or 3n+1 etc...
 });
```

These are just a couple of quick examples obviously there are a lot of ways to traverse and select.

Comment: The `slice()` worked, but `:nth:child()` did not with the versions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

html:

```
<ul class="tablist">
  <li class="tab">a</li>
  <li class="tab">b</li>
  <li class="tab">c</li>
  <li class="tab">d</li>
  <li class="tab">e</li>
</ul>
```

javascript:

```
var tabs = $(document).find('.tablist .tab');
var tabsToToggle = { 0, 3, 4 }
for (var i=0;i<tabsToSet.length;i++)
{ 
   tabs.eq(i).toggle();
}
```

Tested with jQuery 1.10.1, 2.0.2, and 1.x edge on jsFiddle

Comment: I want to set CSS style visibility or display for specified tabs. `.toggle` option may be slower to display.

Comment: That was a good reference opinion for `.toggle()`, thank you.